# My hex values are converted to int while passing as args

Tags: python, integer, hex

I am creating an usb connection, and this works.

```
device = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x47f, idProduct=0x2e6)
```

According to signature of the method, those arguments are passed to method as *args*

```
def find(find_all=False, backend = None, custom_match = None, **args):
```

I want to make class that uses this method, and can take same input, smth like:

```
    class MyNewClass(object):
    
        def __init__(self, find_all=False, backend=None, custom_match=None, **args):
            self.find_all = find_all
            self.backend = backend
            self.custom_match = custom_match
            self.args = args
    
        def __enter__(self):
            self.device = usb.core.find(find_all=self.find_all, backend=self.backend, custom_match=self.custom_match,
                                        args=self.args)
            return self.device
```

Unfortuantely, that approach tranalates input hex values to int, and this is smth that *usb.core.find* cannot take, therefore it returns *None*

```
    with MyNewClass(idVendor=0x47f, idProduct=0x2e6) as aaa:
        aaa = ''
```

[image]

I would like to avoid that conversion, and I am looking for ideas.

Comment: For Python, `0x47F` **is** the same exact value as normal integer `1151`. There is no conversion taking place at runtime.

Comment: Hex notation is just another way to specify an integer literal.  Internally there is no distinction.  Both `0x12` and `18` encode the same value and are identical.  You can freely interchange them in your code and your program will behave the same.  To say a function take a "hex" argument is really just a way of saying it takes an integer argument which is most naturally thought of as a hex value.  It can't tell the difference.  In your original example, try changing `0x47f` to `1151`.  It will behave identically.

Comment: Then my issue lies somewhere else... This is what bugged me, as I thjought the same way as you, but i cannot find another reason, why this isn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `usb.core.find`, you're doing:

```
self.device = usb.core.find(find_all=self.find_all, 
                            backend=self.backend, 
                            custom_match=self.custom_match,
                            args=self.args)
```

This won't pass the keyword args properly.  Change it to:

```
self.device = usb.core.find(find_all=self.find_all, 
                            backend=self.backend, 
                            custom_match=self.custom_match,
                            **self.args)
```

This will correctly pass the dictionary entries in `self.args` as keyword arguments.

Comment: calling this `kwargs` instead of `args` would probably clear things up a bit.

Comment: Ah, you;re probably right! (btw, i didn't changed args to kwargs - that should be proper, as in usb library kwargs are args ;?)

Comment: They seem to be called `args` in library code, so you may stick with that for consistency or change to `self.kwargs` on your side to reduce future confusion. Up to you.